# json_encode() doesn't display arabic characters (opendir)

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$files = array();
$dir = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/files/'.$fil_fi_row['file_name'].'/');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $allfiles[] = $file;
}

$total_arr=array_merge((array)$id,(array)$files);
sort($total_arr);
foreach($total_arr as $key=>$file){
    if($key != count($total_arr)-1)
        $array[‘Files’][] = array(                                         
            ‘files’ => $file,
            ‘id’ => $id,
        );
    }
}   
echo  json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

I tried `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` but does not work; 
ERROR

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in /home/...

Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home/..
```

When I use

```
echo  json_encode($array);
```

the Arabic file name appears as:

```
8508_\u0645\u0635\u0631 \u0627\u0643\u0631\u0645 20150908
```

Comment: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` was introduced with PHP 5.4

Comment: show the `$array` contents

Comment: RomanPerekhrest  see the code now ...thanks

Comment: I fixed some wrong quotes in the second line of your code; I assume you have that right in your own code (otherwise it would not work at all).

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, **ALWAYS** post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ? If there's an error, you won't see a "***blank page***"

Comment: could you provide the output when you do `var_export ($array);` just before the `json_encode()`? The Arabic file name would probably be correct ***IF*** there were backslashes before each `u`. Did you use `stripslashes()` anywhere?

Comment: trincot i do not use stripslashes() arabic file name 8508_\u0645\u0635\u0631 \u0627\u0643\u0631\u0645 20150908

Comment: Pedro Lobito .. error : Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' in dir ... Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in

Comment: @user6107006 you php version  is < PHP5.4.0

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6771980/797495 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16898723/797495

Comment: oh >> PHP Version  5.3.29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined constant JSON\_UNESCAPED\_UNICODE in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925023/undefined-constant-json-unescaped-unicode-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need To Add The following Code

```
header('Content-Type: applcation/json; charset = utf-8');
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try this (PHP5.4.0+)

```
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: It means your PHP version is < 5.4